# Is there any other way to see a function's body than toString()

Tags: javascript

I don't want third party JS to see the code of the functions I expose so I've overridden their .toString method.

Is there any other way to expose the function code than toString ?

Thanks!

Comment: Find the function definition in the library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A custom `toString` property isn't sufficient, because `Function.prototype.toString` can be called on the function:

```js
function foo() {
  console.log('foo implementation');
};
foo.toString = () => 'hidden';
console.log(Function.prototype.toString.call(foo));
```

Currently, there's no way to fully hide the implementation without overwriting `Function.prototype.toString` beforehand so that nothing can reference and call it later (which would be a really weird solution), eg:

```
Function.prototype.toString = () => 'nope';
```

but even that [isn't foolproof](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-function-implementation-hiding#delete-functionprototypetostring) in multi-realm environments.

---

There may eventually be a **proper** way to do this with the [implementation hiding proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-function-implementation-hiding). Its syntax is similar to `use strict`, except that it will prevent external consumers of the function from being able to see anything inside. For example:

```
const y = () => {
  "hide source";
  // implement y here
  // nothing outside will be able to see its source code (easily)
};
```

The proposal is only at stage 2, but it's expected to make its way into the official language eventually.

---

All that said - these techniques can be used to make it *more difficult* for third-party code to see what you're doing, but they don't *guarantee* it - after all, anyone who cared to could look at your code manually and see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks a lot for very valuable info @CertainPerformance. Didn't think of the problem with call. 

I'll then put my function that won't be exposed into one that is exposed so when call is done on the exposed it'll be:

`function foo(){ return _foo(); }`

Comment: @user139643 anybody with a debugger can just follow that `_foo` to where it's defined. Or they can just look at the source code and find it anyway. Hiding the code *only* matters if anybody wants to `eval` it or equivalent but that should be exceedingly rare.